# CSC Compile Error CS0116

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

I am attempting to compile a few CS files into a .dll and am getting Error CS0116.

[image]

I have tried searching and looking up what this error code means, and I got mixed results, ranging from "something is off in your code" to "youre missing a header" and I cant fix it.

Any help?

```
<Project xmlns="Chatterbot">
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="3.5" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<PropertyGroup>
<Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
<Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
<ProductVersion>9.0.21022</ProductVersion>
<SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
<ProjectGuid>{2E624962-F155-432C-A90A-E1CE75DEE9EA}</ProjectGuid>
<OutputType>Library</OutputType>
<RootNamespace>ChatterBotAPI</RootNamespace>
<AssemblyName>ChatterBotAPI</AssemblyName>
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v2.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
<DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
<DebugType>full</DebugType>
<Optimize>false</Optimize>
<OutputPath>bin/Debug</OutputPath>
<DefineConstants>DEBUG</DefineConstants>
<ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
<WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
<ConsolePause>false</ConsolePause>
</PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
<DebugType>none</DebugType>
<Optimize>false</Optimize>
<OutputPath>bin/Release</OutputPath>
<ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
<WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
<ConsolePause>false</ConsolePause>
</PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="AssemblyInfo.cs" />
    <Compile Include="ChatterBotFactory.cs" />
    <Compile Include="ChatterBotType.cs" />
    <Compile Include="ChatterBot.cs" />
    <Compile Include="ChatterBotSession.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Cleverbot.cs" />
    <Compile Include="ChatterBotThought.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Utils.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Pandorabots.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)/Microsoft.CSharp.targets"/>
</Project>
```

Comment: I'm guessing you shouldn't include the `.csproj` file when using `csc` directly from the command-line?   It is probably trying to compile it like a regular `.cs` file.  If you want to build a project, use `MSBuild`.

Comment: Ive been trying to do this for about 3 or 4 hours, what is MSBuild and how do I use it?

Comment: [MSBuild](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd393574.aspx) is the tool that understands how to build .NET projects.  It is used behind the scenes in Visual Studio for example.  Do you have Visual Studio installed?  If not you can try installing [Build Tools 2013](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40760).  With MSBuild you can simply type `MSBuild` from the same folder and it automatically figures out all the files to compile from the project file without any additional arguments.

Comment: Don't include the .csproj. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd.aspx

Comment: I didn't include csproj and didn't get an error, but where does the .dll get dumped?

Comment: The very same directory.

Comment: It was in a different directory, but I still found it. Thanks for the help.